# 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found.- CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello guys i try to working on CodeIgniter 1.7.1 i have done step to step installing 
 but its showing Error
**404 Page Not Found**
The page you requested was not found.

here is codes i used

**controller home.php**

```
class Home extends Controller {
       function __construct()
       {
        parent:: __construct();
        //$this->output->enable_profiler();
        $this->load->library('DX_Auth'); 

    }
```

**Models homemodel.php**

```
class HomeModel extends Model {


    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::Model();

    }
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|xcache|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

i using localhost "XAMPP"

please help me

**and main index.php**

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $system_folder = "system";


    $application_folder = "application";


if (strpos($system_folder, '/') === FALSE)
{
    if (function_exists('realpath') AND @realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_folder = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$system_folder;
    }
}
else
{
    // Swap directory separators to Unix style for consistency
    $system_folder = str_replace("\\", "/", $system_folder); 
}


define('EXT', '.'.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
define('FCPATH', __FILE__);
define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
define('BASEPATH', $system_folder.'/');

if (is_dir($application_folder))
{
    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
}
else
{
    if ($application_folder == '')
    {
        $application_folder = 'application';
    }

    define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
}

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| LOAD THE FRONT CONTROLLER
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| And away we go...
|
*/
require_once BASEPATH.'codeigniter/CodeIgniter'.EXT;

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./index.php */
```

**Server error Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in /hermes/bosoraweb075/b2180/ipg.djsaifnycom/paly/system/application/controllers/home.php on line 21**

```
function index()
{
    $data['memcache'] = new Memcache;
    $data['memcache']->pconnect('localhost', 11211) or $memcache = false;
    //$this->output->cache(60);
    $this->load->model('dx_auth/UserModel', 'user');
    $this->load->model('homemodel');
    $data['title'] = "Home";

    if($this->dx_auth->is_logged_in())
    {
        $query = $this->user->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('DX_user_id'));
        //now we get personalized

        $row = $query->row();
        $data['feedFilter'] = $row->feed_filter;
        $data['feedView'] = $row->feed_view;
        if($data['feedFilter'] == 'tagged')
        {
            $data['feedList'] = null;
            $data['feedList'] = $data['memcache']->get('feed' . $data['feedFilter'] . $row->feed_view);
            if($data['feedList'] == null)
            {           
                $data['albums'] = $this->homemodel->getTagged();
            }
        } else {
            $data['feedList'] = null;
            $data['feedList'] = $data['memcache']->get('feed' . $data['feedFilter'] . $row->feed_view);
            if($data['feedList'] == null)
            {
                $data['albums'] = $this->homemodel->getFeedNoUser();
            }
        }
        //$this->output->enable_profiler();
        $this->template->write('title', 'Home');
        $this->template->write_view('content', 'home/index', $data, TRUE);
        $this->template->render();


    } else {
        $data['feedFilter'] = 'all';
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
        if(get_cookie('unravel_feedView'))
        {
            $data['feedView'] = 0;
        } else {
            $data['feedView'] = 1;
        }

        //this would be generic feed here
        $data['feedList'] = null;
        $data['feedList'] = $data['memcache']->get('feed' . $data['feedFilter'] . $data['feedView']);
        if($data['feedList'] == null)
        {
            $data['albums'] = $this->homemodel->getFeedNoUser();
        }
        $this->template->write('title', 'Home');
        $this->template->write_view('content', 'home/index', $data, TRUE);
        $this->template->render();
    }



    //$this->load->view('home/index', $data);
    //$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
}
```

**the line is** 
***$data['memcache'] = new Memcache;***

Comment: What URL are you accessing, and also is your index.php in the root web folder?

Comment: i use localhost/cashmusic

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `CI 1.7.1` released `February 10, 2009` when `CI 2.1.3` released `October 8, 2012` is available? If you are just now making this application, you should develop it using the latest version of CI. It's hard to provide support on such an old version.

Comment: i use this because this is a music application developing by some other developer and they used it.. that for i try to use it now you can see the full source by this link https://bitbucket.org/snaver/unravel-the-music/src/6893bedf3822630856195384f7c30c0d865fccf5/htdocs?at=default        if you have any solution to use this perfectly please

Comment: From the above url, it seem that your application folder is in your system folder? If that is the case, you will need to update your index.php to load the application files from the correct directory. `$application_folder = "system/application";`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the .htaccess is not in the correct directory.. you may want to check it, should be inside your project directory. if so,

put this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: yes its in correct directory localhost/cashmusic/.htaccess                                                             no boss still same error

Comment: ok boss i installed in my web server but its give me this "Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in .../../.../paly/system/application/controllers/home.php on line 21                           i am putting the code on top

Comment: maybe you need to enable the rewrite module..

a2enmod rewrite

then restart your apache server
you will also need to install memcache.

sudo apt-get install php5-memcache

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also check your `httpd.conf` file and see if apache is allowed to "honor" your .htaccess file. Search for the `AllowOverride` command and change it from `AllowOverride None` (the default) to `AllowOverride All`.

**ALSO:** Do not forget to restart the httpd server afterwards.